# Labelary QrCode PNG Image to String conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to create a zpl label using a png image.  My png image is simply a qr code.

When I go to labelary.com/viewer.html it converts my png image into a some type of string.  My sticking point is that I don't know what type of conversion it's using to create this new string.

According to documentation at https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf I should be able to convert my png into an ascii hexadecimal string.  However, when I do that, it looks completely different than what labelary generates and doesn't work at all.

Can someone help me figure out how to properly convert my png image into a string that ZPL can recognize?  Here's the link to my image:

https://img42.com/Pkqbl

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could bypass the image conversion and use the QR code (^BQ) of ZPL directly?

An example as from the Zebra documentation (page 103-104):

```
^XA
^FO100,100
^BQN,2,10
^FDMM,AAC-42^FS
^XZ
```

Example output:
http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%5EXA%0A%5EFO100%2C100%0A%5EBQN%2C2%2C10%0A%5EFDMM%2CAAC-42%5EFS%0A%5EXZ%0A%0A%5EXZ